# Gradle jettyRuns works but no dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, gradle

I am trying to make this application work and the building is configured in gradle. When I use jettyRun in cmd to run the application it works as expected however when I open the actuall code in eclipse I am missing all of these dependecies such as spring or hibernate and others... I am unsure how to resolve this

The gradle.build looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

// JDK 7
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

     compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
     compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
     compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
     compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE'
     compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.6.RELEASE'
     compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
     compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
     compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final'
     compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.10.Final'   
}

// Embeded Jetty for testing
jettyRun{
    contextPath = "etnshop"
    httpPort = 8080
}

jettyRunWar{
    contextPath = "etnshop"
    httpPort = 8080
}

//For Eclipse IDE only
eclipse {

  wtp {
    component {

      //define context path, default to project folder name
      contextPath = 'etnshop'

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command `gradle eclipse` fixed the problem.